# check overlap Elements in Playing Cards List

Tags: python, python-3.x, playing-cards

i just ask here for the first time.

i made the BlackJack for discord.py
but sometimes this was returned me 'None'
so i tried the debug and found the cause.

```
def deck(self):
    card_type = ["Club ", "Diamond ", "Spade ", "Heart "]
    card_nums = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "K", "Q", "A"]
    cards_total = [i + j for i in card_type for j in card_nums]
    random.shuffle(cards_total)
    pop_card = cards_total.pop()

    if pop_card in self.overlap_check:
        Test.deck(self)
        return
    self.overlap_check.append(pop_card)
    return self.overlap_check[-1]
```

if i tried this itself, it works fine. but if i call the func = deck(self), sometimes i could see the return result to None. according i think this error is occured by there.

```
    if pop_card in self.overlap_check:
        Test.deck(self)
        return
```

but i couldn't think more how to remake this Algorithm.
please let me know how to overap check in list and break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your If block by -

```
    if pop_card in self.overlap_check:
        return Test.deck(self)
```

The problem is : when `pop_card in self.overlap_check` is true then script is calling the function 2nd time here: `Test.deck(self)` so lets say the 2nd call of the function returned "Club 2". Now next line `return` will be executed and it will return None. Hence remove that line directly return the value which the 2nd function call is returning.